# C random integer generator question (A book on C 4th Edition)

Tags: c, random, c-standard-library

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   int i, n;

   printf("\n%s\n%s",
     "Some randomly distributed integers will be printed.",
     "How many do yo want to see? ";
   scanf("%d", &n);
   for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
     if (i % 10 == 0)
       putchar('\n');
     printf("%7d", rand());
   }
   printf("\n\n");
   return 0;
}
```

this is the code from the textbook "A book on C".

when you type 23 when prompted it is supposed to generate 23 random numbers in 3 rows, 8 columns (3*8-1).

i learned that `printf("%7d", rand())`is supposed to return a value printed in a format of a decimal integer and the width of the field where the integer gets printed is 7.

however, I am getting random numbers that are in a width of more than 7 and it doesn't look neat at all. (no columns nor rows, just a huge chunk of consecutive numbers like 1235289043528935294835698246182965982)

I thought it has something to do with the expression `printf("%7d", rand())` function and the way how it is supposed to return values.

I'm starting to think that the textbook is wrong.

Comment: It would be far more usual to take `n` as an argument.  eg `int main(int argc, char *argv) { int i, n = argc > 1 ? strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10) : 10;` and then invoke the program with an argument. (eg `./a.out 23`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your numbers are bigger than 7 digits. You can try:

**A)** Changing the width field higher:

```
printf("%14d", rand() );
```

or

**B)** Making the generated numbers smaller than 7 digits:

```
printf("%7d", rand() % 1000 );
```

More information on format specifiers can be found [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are not printing any whitespace.  Try inserting some:

```
printf("%7d\t", rand());
```

Comment: yes, adding a white space partially helps by adding coordination to the output but it has not solved the issue with the width of the field (which is supposed to be 7). my code generates far more numbers like 9 or 10 in width..

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comment above, if I understand correctly you want all 8 numbers then the line should be changed to be: if (i % 8 == 0);

Answer (score 0):

Rather than guess the maximum width of a `rand()` number, calculate the width of maximum random number: `RAND_MAX`.

`snprintf(NULL, 0, ...` prints the number of characters that would have been written had the buffer been sufficiently large, not counting the terminating null character.

```
int width = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", RAND_MAX);
```

Later when printing, use the width.

```
printf(" %*d", width, rand());
```

as in

```
#define COLUMN_N 8
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  printf(" %*d", width, rand());
  if (i % COLUMN_N == COLUMN_N - 1 || i + 1 == n) {
    putchar('\n');
  }
}
```